# HTML hyperlink stay at same spot

Tags: jquery, html

I  have the following link:

```
    <a id="readmore" href="#">READ MORE</a>
```

When the user clicks on this hyperlink, I am using Jquery to toggle the content below this link to show/hide content. One issue that I have with the href="#" is that it brings the user to the top of the page. Instead I would like it stay at the same location, so that I can show the toggle effect of the info below the READ MORE hyperlink. Is there a solution that will work and is safe for most browers. I tried href="" but that did not do the trick.

I tried also

```
    <a id="readmore"href="javascript:void(0)"> READ MORE</a>
```

but was not sure if this is the best practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
$('#readmore').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

preventDefault() stops the default behaviour of the element so in this case, it'll stop the screen jumping.

Read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Answer (score 3):

A very know issue use `javascript:void(0)` instead of #

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to either use e.preventDefault(); (assuming your event variable is e) or just return false at the end of your click method

Comment: Actually you want to prevent the  default action not stop the propagation.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been so long you're absolutely right, I normally just return false

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the old-school style ...

```
<a id="readmore" href="javascript:void(0);">Read More</a>
```

**UDPATE**

The OP amended his post to include 'best practices' ... As such ...

[Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: Just a note, this is not recommended anymore, inline js makes for unmaintainable code. If you have a hundred links this could get ugly really fast.

Comment: Yeah ... that's why I used the 'old-school' disclaimer ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to pass an event variable and call preventDefault to prevent the default operation of the anchor tag.

ie

```
$('#readmore').click(function(e) {
    $('div').toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use `nohref="nohref"` instead of `href="#"`

`href="#anchor"` brings you to the `<a></a>` element on the page that has defined `name="anchor"`

and since you have not.. It goes to the top